# Conversion error in EXCEPT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please see the below SQL

```
SELECT 3 [COL]
EXCEPT
SELECT CAST(1.24 AS DECIMAL(10,3)) [COL]

result
3.000
```

Here, It appears like 3 was converted into decimal(10,3).

See the next SQL,

```
SELECT 1 [COL]
EXCEPT
SELECT CAST(1.24 AS NVARCHAR(10)) [COL]

result
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1.24' to data type int.
```

Here, It appears like, 1.24 was converted to INT.

If we make the 1 as 1.0 (decimal), again the sql works fine.

```
SELECT 1.0 [COL]
EXCEPT
SELECT CAST(1.24 AS NVARCHAR(10)) [COL]

result:
1.0
```

Why is it behaving in a contrasting manner, or is the 2nd error displayed in a misleading fasion.?

Comment: [Data type precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190309.aspx): "When an operator combines two expressions of different data types, the rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher precedence"

Comment: int trumps char - Data Type Precedence; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190309.aspx

Comment: 1.24 is treated as string, 1 is treated as number even if u convert it. In other way it tries to take the form of first select 1 int except 3 varchar is treated as 1 int except 3 int . But 1 int except 1.24 varchar cannot as it cannot force a decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first query, `SELECT 3 [COL]` yields an `INT` and `SELECT CAST(1.24 AS DECIMAL(10,3)) [COL]` yields a `DECIMAL`; [data type precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190309.aspx) means a `DECIMAL` is attempted, and `1.24` is converted successfully.

In the second query, `SELECT 3 [COL]` yields an `INT` and `SELECT CAST(1.24 AS NVARCHAR(10)) [COL]` yields a `NVARCHAR`; [data type precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190309.aspx) means an `INT` is attempted, but `1.24` is better as a `DECIMAL`.

In the third query, `SELECT 1.0 [COL]` yields a `DECIMAL` and `SELECT CAST(1.24 AS NVARCHAR(10)) [COL]` yields a `NVARCHAR`; [data type precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190309.aspx) means a `DECIMAL` is attempted, and `1.24` is converted successfully.

In summary:

- `DECIMAL` before `INT`
- `INT` before `NVARCHAR`

Comment: Credit for the link to Data Type Precedence should go to the commenters on the question.